# Password strengthening script - how to capitalise first letter and append list of integers to end of text in file and list it repeatedly

Tags: python, append

Im currently writing a basic python script that is meant to do the following:

1. Take a file of passwords as input
2. Perform the following transformation on each password and write to a new file:

reverse it (e.g. password becomes drowssap)

substitute all ‘o’ for ‘0’, ‘a’ for ‘4’ and ‘s’ for ‘5’ (e.g. password becomes p455w0rd

makes the first character uppercase (e.g password becomes Password)

appends all years from 1900 to 2014 to the password, e.g. password1900, password1901,…,password2014

---

The "passwordlist.txt" in my example contains one line of text being "password".

My code so far is:

```
reading_file = open("passwordlist.txt", "r")

new_file_content = ""
for line in reading_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    new_line = stripped_line.replace("a", "4").replace("o", "0").replace("s", "5").replace("d", "D")
    new_file_content += "\n" + new_line
reading_file.close()

writing_file = open("hashedpasslist.txt", "w")
years = map(str, range(1900, 2014))
writing_file.write(new_file_content[::-1])
writing_file.close()
```

I need assistance in making the first character of the output file uppercase, is you can see ive only managed to swap 'd' for 'D'. And lastly I'd like to append all years from 1900 to 2014 to the password, so the output should be e.g. Dr0w554p1900, Dr0w554p,…,Dr0w554p2014 preferably in a listed format.

Answer (score 0):

You can uppercase the first character with the following snippet

`string[0].upper() + string[1:]`

Which in your code would be:

```
reading_file = open("passwordlist.txt", "r")

new_file_content = ""
for line in reading_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    new_line = stripped_line.replace("a", "4").replace("o", "0").replace("s", "5")
    new_line = new_line[0].upper() + new_line[1:]
    new_file_content += "\n" + new_line
reading_file.close()

writing_file = open("hashedpasslist.txt", "w")
years = map(str, range(1900, 2014))
writing_file.write(new_file_content[::-1])
writing_file.close()
```

As for the years, you will want to iterate through each year, append it to the string and output it to a list.

eg.

```
output = []
for year in range(1900, 2015):
    appended_line = new_line + str(year)
    output.append(appended_line)
```

Your final code would look like this:

```
reading_file = open("passwordlist.txt", "r")
writing_file = open("hashedpasslist.txt", "w")

new_file_content = ""
for line in reading_file:
    reversed_line = line[::-1]
    stripped_line = reversed_line.strip()
    new_line = stripped_line.replace("a", "4").replace("o", "0").replace("s", "5").replace("d", "D")
    for year in range(1900, 2015):
        appended_line = new_line + str(year)
        new_file_content += "\n" + appended_line
        writing_file.write(new_file_content)

reading_file.close()
writing_file.close()
```

I made a couple changes. Firstly, the string is reversed at the start (I forgot, you can't reverse a string with `reversed()`, oops). Then, you'll see that for each password it loops through all the years, appends it to the password and finally writes it to the file.

Comment: Much appreciated! As write the output reversed at the end, i need to change [0] to [7] but works amazing! Do you have any idea how to iterate through each year and do that ?

Comment: @darkrai0101 Firstly, don't use [7] as it will only work on 8 character passwords, but instead use [-1] which will always be the last character. I have edited to provide code for the years, which outputs to a list.

Comment: Thanks again -1 seems to actually change the last letter of the output. However ill just use 0 for now as it works good enough :). Apologies im very new to coding, where exactly would i place the iteration piece you've written within my own code ?

Comment: @darkrai0101 it would replace 'years = map(str, range(1900, 2014))', but it produces a list of all the passwords which you will have to do something with (such as individually writing on a new line). I would recommend reversing the input string using reversed() rather than reversing the output upon writing to the file.

Comment: It seems to have no effect, unless ive place it incorrectly. Also i tried using reversed() previously but kept encountering errors which is why i resulted to reversing it upon writing to the file

Comment: @darkrai0101 I edited with final code with everything where it should be.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate it and wish you the best